# Memory consumption increases after upgrade from postgres 11 to postgres 15

Tags: postgresql, memory

I have some application which make `SELECT` queries to PostgreSQL database. Currently postgres server version is 11.22 (running in docker container from [official image postgres:11.22-alpine3.19](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/tags?page=1&name=11.22-alpine3.19)). I want to upgrade from postgres 11 (which is already unsupported) to postgres 15 (which is quite modern).

I launch new docker container ([official image postgres:15.5-alpine3.19](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/tags?page=1&name=15.5-alpine3.19)), make dump from old postgres and restore this dump to new postgres:

```
pg_dump -C -h 127.0.0.1 -U my_username my_dbname > dump.sql
cat dump.sql | docker compose exec -T new-postgres-container psql -U my_username -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on
```

No problems while dumping and restoring. Then I change settings of my application to work with new database rather than old one and it works fine.

The problem is while answering the same `SELECT` queries, "old" postgres 11 container consumes 100~200 Mb RAM, but "new" postgres 15 container consumes 550~650 Mb RAM, and I can't find the reason.

Memory usage doesn't increasing over time, it remains within the specified ranges.

Typical `SELECT` from application is (there are 16 such queries running simultaneously with different `ps.name = 'someString'` conditions):

```
select
    ps.name,
    payment_request_id,
    pr.callback_url,
    pr.amount,
    someTable1.created_at as created_at,
    pr.service_order_id as order_id,
    es.other as callback_opts
from someTable1
inner join someTable2 pr on pr.id = someTable1.payment_request_id
inner join someTable3 sc on pr.connection_id = sc.id
inner join someTable4 ps on sc.payment_system_id = ps.id
inner join someTable5 es on sc.external_service_id = es.id
where
    ps.name = 'someString' and
    (select count(id) from someTable1 as s where s.payment_request_id=pr.id and s.someParam != 'value') = 0
```

What have I checked and done for now:

- old container is working with unmodified official docker images, no plugins installed
- there are no extra config files, ENV or cli arguments passed to the postgres in old container
- both old and new containers runs on the same server, docker volumes are stored on the same disk
- problem **does not** reproduce, if I run completely new `postgres:11.22-alpine3.19` container and restore dump onto it
- problem **does** reproduce, if I run completely new `postgres:12.17-alpine3.19 | postgres:13.13-alpine3.19 | postgres:14.10-alpine3.19 | postgres:15.5-alpine3.19 | postgres:16.1-alpine3.19` container and restore dump onto it
- there are no differences in [resource consumption related settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-resource.html) between postgres 11 and postgres 15, except `vacuum_cost_page_miss` (old: 10, new: 2) and `hash_mem_multiplier` (old: no setting at all, new: 2), changing `vacuum_cost_page_miss` to 10 and `hash_mem_multiplier` to 1 doesn't solve the problem
- doing `REINDEX DATABASE my_dbname` doesn't solve the problem
- doing `VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE) all, tables, in, my, database` doesn't solve the problem
- setting `enable_seqscan = OFF` doesn't solve the problem
- setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0` doesn't solve the problem

What could be the reason for RAM consumption increases after upgrade from postgres 11 to postgres 15 (12, 13, 14, 16)? How to reduce it back?

Comment: Does the memory usage keep increasing (potential memory leak)? Does the problem go away if you set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0? What if you set `jit = off`? Is the memory released if you restart the application (not the database), which could indicate a per-session memory leak? Is there anything beside the database running in the container? How do you measure memory usage?

Comment: Setting `jit = off` has an effect: "new" postgres 15 container now consumes ~308 Mb RAM, which is still more than "old" postgres 11 (100~200), but less than with `jit = on` (550~650).

Comment: Does the memory usage keep increasing? - No, it remains within the specified ranges.  

Is there anything beside the database running in the container? - No. 

How do you measure memory usage? - "MEM USAGE" column in `docker stats` output.

Setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: A memory leak with JIT [was fixed](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=aef521849b68d1eeb63c3dfbc4e92d66dc94a636) in November 2023. Are you running the latest minor release? But apart from that, parallel query creates shared memory segments for data exchange, which may explain the difference. I wonder why you are worrying, because the memory footprint is tiny (less than 1GB).

Comment: Both 15.5  and 16.1 versions was released 2023-11-09, and the commit you are pointing to was introduced 2023-11-17. Should I wait for the next minor release? "...why you are worrying..." - I run docker on 2Gb-only box, and there are other containers nearby.

Comment: You could wait, yes. But if the memory usage does not keep increasing, it may be a different problem. I would just disable JIT. Running a database in such a memory constrained environment is not a good idea, particularly if you are running queries that are expensive enough to trigger JIT.